# Can't display 404 page in development environment

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

From the guide http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/views it says that I should be able to display the 404 page when I set `debug_errors: false` in `config/dev.exs`. However, it sends 404 and displays **"Something went wrong"** when I'm expecting **"Page not found"**. Btw I do get "page not found" in production.

```
config :myapp, Myapp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: false,
  code_reloader: true,
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: [node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch", "--stdin",
                    cd: Path.expand("../", __DIR__)]]
```

Comment: I get `Page not found` after setting `debug_errors: false`. Could you add your `config/dev.exs` file to the question?

Comment: @Dogbert of course.

Comment: `use Plug.ErrorHandler` in router seems to be causing the issue. This only happens in development environment though.